# Expression Engine channel content not showing

Tags: channel-entries, channel, pages, page-uri

I am new to expression engine.
I have a channel name "news" and I have published some pages. In my template, I have used code as

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news"}
  <h2>{title}<h2>
  {body}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But the output is **I get the page title but the content doesn't shows up and i get `{body}` as it is on the frontend**

Can anyone help me please, where I am doing wrong.

ANy help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure that you have created a [Channel Field Group](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/custom_channel_fields.html) and assigned that to your [Channel](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/channel_groups.html) (News). Then, make sure that you have created at least one field in your Channel Field Group. In this case it would be a [Textarea Field Type with a name of `body`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/custom_fields_edit.html).

Then in your Publish/Edit screen for your Channel you'll see your new Body field. Once you enter in some text into this field and save the Entry you should see the results appear in your templates.